# How to find max value in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a table named StatementSummary.

```
SELECT * 
FROM StatementSummary 
WHERE AccountID = 1234
```

Results

```
StatementId StatementDate   AccountId   AmountDue
-------------------------------------------------
100     2017-10-16  1234        600
99      2017-09-16  1234        500
98      2017-08-16  1234        400
```

I have another table that has a list of Accounts. I am trying to give results that show the last `AmountDue` for each account

My code:

```
SELECT 
    AccountID,
    (SELECT MAX(StatementDate) 
     FROM StatementSummary 
     GROUP BY AccountID) LastStatementDate,
    AmountDue
FROM
    Accounts A
INNER JOIN 
    StatementSummary S ON A.AccountId = S.AccountId
```

Basically, I want to show all the details of the last statement for every `AccountId`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Derived Table over `row number`and `left join` - to display all accounts regardless if there is a statement

```
select * 
from
(select row_number() over (partition by accountid order by statementdate desc) rn,
   accountid, statementdate,amount
from statementtable
) l
left outer join accountstable a
 on l.accountid = a.accountid
 And l.rn = 1
```

Comment: `max(amount)` will return max amount per accountid, not amount of the latest record in the statement table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL Server Windowing functions in cases like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        a.AccountId,
        FIRST_VALUE(s.StatementDate) OVER (PARTITION BY s.AccountId ORDER BY s.StatementDate DESC) As LastStatementDate,
        FIRST_VALUE(s.AmountDue) OVER (PARTITION BY s.AccountId ORDER BY s.StatementDate DESC) As LastAmountDue
        FROM Accounts a
        INNER JOIN StatementSummary s
            ON a.AccountId = s.AccountId
```

Basically what happens is the OVER clause creates partitons in your data, in this case, by the account number (these partitions are the windows).  We then tell SQL Server to sort the data within each partition by the statement date in  descending order, so the last statement will be at the top of the partition, and then the FIRST_VALUE function is used to just grab the first row.

Finally, since you perform this operation for every account/statement combo between the two tables, you need the DISTINCT to say you just want one copy of each row for each account.

There are quite a bit of useful things you can do with the windowing functions in SQL Server.  This article gives a good introduction to them: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/

Comment: Just to make it more readable, convert your window clause to the named one.

Comment: I got the following error message when running this code: 'FIRST_VALUE' is not a recognized built-in function name. __ Pehaps, this is an Oracle only function?

Comment: @user1777929 - it looks like FIRST_VALUE has been around since SQL Server 2012 according to the docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql.  Are you running on an older compatibility level perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

*That's sounds like a job for me* sings lateral join aka [`cross apply`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) in T-SQL.

```
 SELECT a.*, last_ss.*
 FROM Accounts A
 cross apply (
  select top 1 * 
  from StatementSummary S ON A.AccountId = S.AccountId 
  order by StatementDate desc
  ) last_ss
```

Alternatively you can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to get last date for account:

```
 ; with l as (
   select accountid, max(StatementDate) 
   from StatementSummary
   group by accountid
 )
 select ...
 from Accounts a
   inner join l on l.accountid = a.accountid
   inner join StatementSummary ss on ss.accountid = a.accountid 
                  and l.StatementDate = ss.StatementDate
```

Comment: `limit` is mysql...OP is SQL Server

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yeah that should've been  `top 1`

Comment: without the `desc` will not get the latest statement date